# No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669 with RN v0.63.3

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using React Native v0.63.3. Initially NDK Version is not in my code. recently, the build getting failed in github actions. so the error comes like this,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2V16.png

So that I have added the NDK version to build.gradle file and updates some other things.
again I'm facing the issue like below this,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CnRb.png

```
Platform = Android

Node v14.17.5

Android studio Version = 4.1.2
```

**build.gradle file looks like,**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "21.0.6113669"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**In gradle-wrapper.properties,**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
```

How can I solve this issue ? Please share your thoughts! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The second error tells you that the CI machine doesn't have the NDK you requested installed and gives a list of the NDKs it does have. The one you picked is the completely unpatched r21. r21 is no longer in support in any form. You should be using the r23 build.

AGP is supposed to auto download NDKs that are requested but not installed, but perhaps your AGP version (not mentioned) is too old for that.